# Text column issues while converting xlsx to to csv

Tags: csv, xlsx, file-conversion

I am having troubles converting a xlsx file to csv format. Somehow it does not copy the contents of the columns that contain text.

I tried : python xlsx2csv-0.20/xlsx2csv.py -s 2 -d ';' 'testin.xlsx'  'testout.csv'

The result should look like:

"www.vistaheads.com";"http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-general/200274-vista-mbr-vs-xp-mbr-4.html";"YahooBossAPIv2";;"eng";"ie";;9/8/2010;TRUE;FALSE;;0;-8.2666666667;0;0;0;0
"www.drpletsch.com";"http://www.drpletsch.com/elos-acne-treatment.html";"Oxyme.Searchv3.0.0";;"eng";;;7/31/2012;TRUE;FALSE;;;;0;0;0;0
"www.charterhouse-aquatics.co.uk";"http://www.charterhouse-aquatics.co.uk/catalog/elos-systemmini-marine-litre-aquarium-black-p-7022.html";"YahooBossAPIv2";;"eng";"us";;7/11/2012;TRUE;FALSE;;1;5.6666666667;0;0;0;0
"www.proz.com";"http://www.proz.com/kudoz/latin_to_english/religion/4794760-concio_melos_tinnulo.html";"YahooBossAPIv2";;"eng";"in";;5/7/2012;TRUE;FALSE;;1;3;0;0;0;0
"schoee.blogspot.co.uk";"http://schoee.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/review-body-shop-vitamin-c-facial.html";"YahooBossAPIv2";;"eng";;;8/1/2010;TRUE;FALSE;;1;1;0;0;0;0

But instead I get:

;;;;;;;09-08-10;TRUE;FALSE;;0.0;-8.266666666666666;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;
;;;;;;;07-31-12;TRUE;FALSE;;;;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;
;;;;;;;07-11-12;TRUE;FALSE;;1.0;5.666666666666667;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;
;;;;;;;05-07-12;TRUE;FALSE;;1.0;3.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;
;;;;;;;08-01-10;TRUE;FALSE;;1.0;1.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;
;;;;;;;09-08-10;TRUE;FALSE;;0.0;0.033333333333333354;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;
;;;;;;;07-03-12;TRUE;FALSE;;1.0;2.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;
;;;;;;;10-18-11;TRUE;FALSE;;1.0;4.666666666666667;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;

I also tried using ssconvert, but here I get similar outcomes i.e. :

ssconvert -S 'testin.xlsx' testout2.csv

Also here the textual contents somehow vanished:

2010/09/08,TRUE,FALSE,,0,-8.26666666666667,0,0,0,0
"2012/07/31 09:58:39.823",TRUE,FALSE,,,,0,0,0,0
"2012/07/11 13:35:09.220",TRUE,FALSE,,1,5.66666666666667,0,0,0,0
2012/05/07,TRUE,FALSE,,1,3,0,0,0,0
2010/08/01,TRUE,FALSE,,1,1,0,0,0,0
2010/09/08,TRUE,FALSE,,0,0.03333333333333,0,0,0,0
"2012/07/03 22:24:03.467",TRUE,FALSE,,1,2,0,0,0,0
2011/10/18,TRUE,FALSE,,1,4.66666666666667,0,0,0,0
"2012/07/22 02:10:58.313",TRUE,FALSE,,1,2,0,0,0,0
"2012/08/02 17:01:39.637",TRUE,FALSE,,1,1,0,0,0,0
2010/06/05,TRUE,FALSE,,1,4,0,0,0,0
"2012/07/25 16:11:47.843",TRUE,FALSE,,1,2,0,0,0,0
2012/09/26,TRUE,TRUE,1,,,1,0,0,1
2012/04/29,TRUE,TRUE,2,,,8,3,1,4
2012/07/22,TRUE,FALSE,,0,0.03333333333333,0,0,0,0
2012/05/01,TRUE,FALSE,,1,14,0,0,0,0
"2012/08/07 06:17:39.647",TRUE,FALSE,,1,1,0,0,0,0
"2012/07/18 15:15:19.283",TRUE,FALSE,,1,3,0,0,0,0
2012/07/27,TRUE,FALSE,,1,0.33333333333333,0,0,0,0
2010/09/08,TRUE,FALSE,,1,0.33333333333333,0,0,0,0
"2012/07/21 18:10:57.700",TRUE,FALSE,,1,0.33333333333333,0,0,0,0

The Excel file looks fine to me. Any ideas what could be going wrong ?

The Excel file is generated using Apache POI, maybe that's a clue?

Kind regards, 
Rianne